# How to restrict 3 LI Elements in one line (Replace HTML Table WITH UL LI)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to replace HTML Table with UL LI. There are three rows and three columns as mentioned below.

```
<html>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<ul style="align:center; width:92%; margin:5px; overflow:hidden; min-width:500px;">
<li style="float:left; display:inline; width:5%; min-height: 50px; ">A</li>
<li style="float:left; display:inline; width:87%; min-height: 50px; ">B</li>
<li style="float:left; display:inline; width:8%; min-height: 50px; "><input type="submit" name="one" id="one" value="one"></input></li>

<li style="float:left; display:inline; width:5%; min-height: 100px; ">A</li>
<li style="float:left; display:inline; width:87%; min-height: 100px; "><div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 100px;" >Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. </div></li>
<li style="float:left; display:inline; width:8%; min-height: 100px; "> &nbsp; C</li>

<li style="float:left; display:block; width:5%; min-height: 100px; "><input type="radio" name="optia" value="a" id="optia" />A</li>
<li style="float:left; display:inline; width:87%; min-height: 100px; "><div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 100px;" >Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. </div></li>
<li style="float:left; display:inline; width:8%; min-height: 100px; "> &nbsp; C</li>

</ul></body></html>
```

I want to ensure there are only 3 li elements in one line. Fourth LI element must start on new line. Here 7th LI element is going along with second line; can you please help to fix this error?

Comment: `clear` the floating for every 4th LI …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html><head></head><body style="margin: 0px;">
<ul style="display: table; text-align:center; width:92%; margin: 5px; padding: 0; overflow:hidden; min-width:500px;">
  <li style="display:table-row; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
      <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:5%; min-height: 50px; ">A</li>
      <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:87%; min-height: 50px; ">B</li>
      <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:8%; min-height: 50px; "><input type="submit" name="one" id="one" value="one"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li style="display:table-row; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
      <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:5%; min-height: 100px; ">A</li>
      <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:87%; min-height: 100px; "><div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 100px;">Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. </div></li>
      <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:8%; min-height: 100px; "> &nbsp; C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li style="display:table-row; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
      <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:5%; min-height: 100px; "><input type="radio" name="optia" value="a" id="optia">A</li>
      <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:87%; min-height: 100px; "><div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 100px;">Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. </div></li>
      <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:8%; min-height: 100px; "> &nbsp; C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```